implementing auto DQ of dataplex as task in cloud composer
I'm exploring Google's native options for ensuring data quality and have come across auto Data Quality (DQ) features within Dataplex in the Google Cloud Platform (GCP) ecosystem. I aim to integrate this auto DQ functionality into my Composer workflow. Are there any Airflow operators designed for invoking Dataplex's auto DQ capabilities? Alternatively, can I utilize the Cloud DQ module as a task within Composer? I'd appreciate your guidance on the most suitable approach for achieving this integration.

Hi there, have you tried this https://airflow.apache.org/docs/apache-airflow-providers-google/stable/operators/cloud/dataplex.html#create-or-update-a-data-quality-scan
